# Grails GSP Exposing errors from expressions (now empty page)

Tags: grails, gsp

I had the following problem when rendering a GSP page due
a configuration variable that could not be found.

```
<g:set var="isFlowEnabled" value="${Boolean.valueOf(grailsApplication?.config?.flowEnabled)}"/>
```

If I put a try catch construction around it

```
try{
   Boolean.valueOf(grailsApplication?.config?.flowEnabled)
} catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace()
}
```

I get this exception in my console log
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static java.lang.Boolean.valueOf() is applicable for argument types: (groovy.util.ConfigObject) values: [[:]]

How do expose this errors to the GSP page or log this to stdout?

Comment: By default Grails will redirect all errors to an error page (as per url routing config) and so the error should be shown there. Is that not the case?

Comment: I have seen the same behaviour on our application, e.g. when a configuration parameter was not found. The page would not render (completely white), and no error page or stacktrace was shown.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but this will avoid the exception: `<g:set var="isFlowEnabled" value="${Boolean.valueOf(grailsApplication?.config?.flowEnabled ?: false)}"/>` - you could also default to true.